# How to make a table display the many rows of a result set in jsp

Tags: jsp

my sql query returns 5 rows and want all 5 rows displayed on a table in jsp, but so far can only display one row, how do i get my table to display all five rows. really need your help guys. thanks.

Comment: Using a loop. Where is your code?

Comment: How many rows did you fetch from the database?

Comment: Was able to fetch only one row